# Grouping selectors in 1 action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a simple issue with grouping jQuery selectors in 1 action.

For example I have a list of variables like:

```
var searchresults        = '#search-results';
var event_two            = '#event-two';
var competition_three    = '#competition-three';
var apparatus_four       = '#apparatus-four';
```

After triggering on change event I have something like this:

```
$("#event_two, #competition_three, #apparatus_four").empty();
```

No problem is I can't get it working. I've tried already in a lot of different ways.

This is how the code snippet of the first part of my code:

```
  $(document).on('change', '#discipline-one', function() {
    var discipline = $(this).val();

    // event_two.empty();
    // competition_three.empty();
    // apparatus_four.empty();

    $("#event_two, #competition_three, #apparatus_four").empty();

    $("#event_two").append("<option selected='true' disabled='disabled'>Please select an event</option>");
    $("#competition_three").append("<option selected='true' disabled='disabled'>Please choose from above</option>");
    $("#apparatus_four").append("<option selected='true' disabled='disabled'>Please choose from above</option>");

    $("#event_two").attr("disabled",true);
    $("#competition_three").attr("disabled",true);
    $("#apparatus_four").attr("disabled",true);

    $.get("getEvents.php?discipline=" + discipline, function(data) {  
      var vals = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

      if(data) {
        $("#event_two").attr("disabled",false);
        $("#event_two").attr("autofocus",true);
      } 

      if($.isArray(vals['Event'])) {
        $.each(vals['Event'], function(k,v){
          $("#event_two").append("<option value='"+v['id']+"'>" + v['name'] + "</option>");
        });
      } else { 
        $("#event_two").append("<option value='"+vals['Event']['id']+"'>" + vals['Event']['name'] + "</option>");
      }

    });
  });
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are those divs, or inputs

Comment: *Welcome to StackOverflow!* Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo:

Here you say:

```
$("#event_two, #competition_three, #apparatus_four").empty();
```

Where you define id's with underscores.

Here you say:

```
var searchresults        = '#search-results';
var event_two            = '#event-two';
var competition_three    = '#competition-three';
var apparatus_four       = '#apparatus-four';
```

Where your id's doesn't contain underscores.

I think you mean: (UPDATE)

```
$(event_two + ', ' + competition_three + ', ' + apparatus_four).empty();
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me, I'm already tried that. This is not a good approach for my code. I won't be able to use them in functions etc.. So that's why I'm refactoring my code.

Answer (score 0):

Like @VDesign said, you define ID's with underscores, but in your variables, you have hyphens. So the following won't work:

```
$("#event_two, #competition_three, #apparatus_four").empty();
```

But when you want to select multiple objects, you have to have one big string with commas, like so:

```
$(event_two + ',' + competition_three + ',' + apparatus_four).empty();
```

See http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ for more details on multiple selectors.

You could even do something like this:

```
$([ event_two, competition_three, apparatus_four ].join(',')).empty();
```

Comment: You're missing a ')' there

Comment: Totally missed that ;)